# Update SQL Server on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to update a particular column of a SQL Server table using my aspx page on button click event. My code is:

```
if (AutoMan.Text == "Auto Mode")
{
    var x = "1";
    var y = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    var z = "1";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
    {
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE AutoManLog SET AutoMan = @data, Time = @data1", con))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data1", y);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", x);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

            Response.Write("Unable To Save Data. Error - " + Ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Data in the database is not updating. I Can't see any error messages.

Comment: No exception? Why don't you add the primary-key to the missing `Where` of your update-query? Do you want to update all rows? Have you used the debugger to see if this code is executed at all?

Comment: What's the return value of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`?

Comment: I cant see any exception messages on the page.

Comment: Try putting a throw; in the catch Statement and let the program run in debug mode.

Comment: The order of the parameters is important when using add with value

Comment: Are you sure AutoMan.Text is actually equal to `"Auto Man"`?

Comment: @SPandya Try using a debugger and please see if you reach your code or not?

Comment: @GrantWinney is spot on, I am almost certain that this is what the problem is. Passing a `DateTime` as a string means you are dictating the format, it's best to let the framework decide on what format it needs - to do that you simply pass the `DateTime` instance in `AddWithValue`. This would most definitely raise an exception.

Comment: @GrantWinney and @James; surprisingly, the code works just like that -- I tried it; that's not the issue.

Comment: I don't know what was causing the problem, But when  just restarted my system after sometime everything just worked fine. Never encountered such issue earlier.

Answer (score 0):

in this query:
"UPDATE AutoManLog SET AutoMan = @data, Time = @data1"
Time is a preserved name for sql server; so use it as **[Time]** will be solve the problem,
if there isn't another problem exist.

Comment: This is not an issue -- SQL server understands that `Time` is in place for a column name and will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I copy-pasted your code and it works just as is; your parameters are correct, and your statement is correct.

Your possible issues are:

- `AutoMan.Text` does not equal `"Auto Man"` -- make sure they are equal
- Any error occurring (database connection, table doesn't exist, etc.), but something is obstructing your `Response.Write` output, not making you able to see the output -- take out the try-catch, and let the debugger catch errors so you can trace it better